# Calling a JavaScript variable inside a function from outside

Tags: javascript

```
var func = function(){
   this.innerVar = 'hello';
}

console.log(func.innerVar); // it prints undefined
```

can I access the variable `innerVar` from outside?

Comment: You can if you create a new instance with the `new` keyword, but then you should also have good reason for actually needing an instance, otherwise you might as well just define a regular variable in a higher scope.

Comment: That's not a variable. It's property assigned to `this`, which can be different in each call. If you want to associate some data to the function itself, you should use `var func = function(){}; func.innerVar = 'hello';`

Comment: This is almost guaranteed an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378) question. What are you actually trying *to do* that makes you ask this?

Comment: Part XY problem, part just not bothering to learn the language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var func = function(){
   this.innerVar = 'hello';
}
```

Now you have these options:

1) Using `func` as a constructor:

```
console.log(new func().innerVar);
```

2) Using the `apply` method on the function:

```
var obj = {};
func.apply(obj);
console.log(obj.innerVar);
```

3) Using the `call` method on the function (cheers to @dev-null):

```
var obj = {};
func.call(obj);
console.log(obj.innerVar);
```

4) Using the `bind` method on the function:

```
var obj = {};
func.bind(obj)();
console.log(obj.innerVar);
```

5) And the crazy stuff:

```
console.log(func.apply(func) || func.innerVar);
```

Comment: @dev-null Haha, yes even better :)

Comment: or `var obj = new func();`,

Comment: or `.apply(obj);` :D

Comment: Anyone more suggestions? :D

Comment: Thanks guys... It really helped

Answer (score 1):

That's basic

```
var func = function(){
   this.innerVar = 'hello';
}

console.log((new func()).innerVar);
```

1. Create a object `new func()`.
2. Set its property innerVar `this.innerVar = 'hello';`.
3. Fetch its property `(new func()).innerVar`

Answer (score 0):

```
var Func = function(){
   this.innerVar = 'hello';
}

var func = new Func; // Creates an instance of your Func class
console.log(func.innerVar);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var func = function() {
  func.innerVar = 'hello';
};

func.innerVar; // undefined
func();
func.innerVar; // ‘hello'
```